# how to wrap a group of spheres around a cylinder

Tags: modifiers

I took the following steps in an attempt to wrap a bunch of spheres around a cylinder.

1. Add a plane mesh
2. add a number of spheres
3. join the spheres into one object
4. parent the plane to the spheres, ie the plane is the parent
5. select the spheres and a surface deform modifier with the plane as the target
6. select the plane and add shrink wrap modifier with the cylinder as the target.

I have tried various wrap methods and snap modes but unfortunately the spheres are distorted on the cylinder. I simply want the spheres to retain its shape but is just sitting on the surface of the cylinder. My final objects will not be spheres some other mesh object.

Any tips are welcome.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use Geometry Nodes to distribute instances on the vertices of the cylinder. Better yet, you can create the cylinder inside GN to keep it all procedural if you'd like that:

[image]

Here's the full node setup:

[image]

And here's the file: [image]

Comment: cool... that looks great! Unfortunately I get an error stating " file written by newer blender binary (300.43) Expect loss of data". I am using 2.93.1

Comment: @user9106985 Geometry Nodes have undergone quite a drastic change with 3.0, so I don't think it would work with 2.93. Just update to the latest version? Latest stable release is 3.1 and that should be fine since I'm not using any nodes that's not available in 3.1, I think (I'm using 3.2 Alpha).

Comment: Many thanks. I had not realized of the new version. Installed and your model works

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to ask further questions if something's not right with the setup for your specific purpose.

Comment: is it possible to replace the cylinder on which the geometry nodes acts with an arbitrary shaped mesh? Ie, a mesh that does not change configuration when we change circular or vertical count for example?

Comment: You can disable the link between "Cylinder" and "Join Geometry" so it doesn't show. If you then link Geometry from the Group Input to it, the object you put the Geometry Nodes modifier on will show up in the middle instead: https://i.imgur.com/kCiH9SM.png Distribution is still based on the cylinder though, do you also want the spheres to "stick" to the geometry in the middle? That'd be a bit more involved.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced the object with a uv sphere and that works however, if I replace it with my target object (a meshed vase), the instances  do not appear. The source of this vase is an stl import not a default blender mesh object. Would that be a limitation?

Comment: I don't think so, no, a mesh is a mesh. If it's an import it could be very big or very small, however. Did you make sure it has an appropriate scale?

Comment: I figured the problem. I actually appended my target geometry as an object instead of the usual import stl. Now it works. Thanks for this cool modifier!

Answer (score 5):

It won't work as the *Shrinkwrap* modifier won't project your plane nicely around your cylinder. There are several ways to do it, like **Simple Deform, Instancing, Particles, Geometry Nodes**...

The easiest is probably to give to your spheres a *Simple Deform (Bend* mode) modifier. Don't forget to apply the rotation of your sphere object. It will deform the spheres a bit though. If you don't want deformation you could use *Instancing* instead.

[image]

For the *Instancing* solution, duplicate a part of your cylinder, separate as a new object, subdivide it so that it has as many vertices as you want instances of your sphere:

[image]

Keep this object selected and in the *Properties panel > Object > Instancing*, click on *Vertices*. You'll be able to hide the object with the visibility options:

[image]

Parent the sphere to this object, it will duplicate the sphere along the object shape. Move the sphere object so that it sticks to the cylinder.

[image]

The *Particle system* solution is a bit more tedious, so it's probably better to use one of the two solutions I've explained, or switch to a more flexible like *Geometry Nodes* as explained by Kuboa.

Comment: thanks for this!

Comment: its not clear to me how to reproduce what you have shown? The blender docs states to select an object that defines the origin and axis of deformation. Thus I have selected the cylinder as the target.

Comment: if you want to use the Simple Deform modifier you don't need the cylinder, by default the bend axis center will be the origin of the object, just don't forget to apply the rotation in Object mode (Ctrl A > Rotation)

Comment: now it works. Thanks! It looks like the distortion is too much for my liking. I presume instancing is what Kuboä is referring to in his post?

Comment: Kuboa's solution is Geometry Nodes based, it's a bit more complicated, I can explain instancing though

Comment: Technically what Geometry Nodes is doing is also instancing, but what moonboots is referring to is an older method of using that duplication method through the Object Properties panel. That can be a simpler and faster way if all you want is placement and not more control like orientation etc.